# Битрикс - как создать каталог товаров?

Tags: битрикс

Не могу понять куда делся каталог товаров во вкладке магазин. По всем картинкам-инструкциям каталог товаров должен быть во вкладке магазин. Но там его нет. Версия 1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом 20.0.0.
Есть -Заказы, Кассы, CRM, Покупатели, Складской учет, Настройки, Установить готовый магазин из маркетплейс и все. Как создается каталог или это какой-то косяк?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел. Нужно зайти в Контент-Инфоблоки-Типы инфоблоков-Каталог и включить Торговый каталог- Является торговым каталогом